# Bindeo de datos en tiempo real con Angular y PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, http, binding, servicio

Realizo una consulta a un archivo .json
y con la respuesta hago una tabla
pero debido a que el archivo .json se actualiza constantemente, necesito estar observando si ese archivo ha cambiado para mostrarlo en tiempo real en la aplicacion, y he intentado pero no consigo el two way data binding.

app.js

```
(function(){
var myapp = angular.module("appMonitor",[]);


myapp.factory('myService', function($http,$timeout) {
  var promise;
  var myService = {
    get: function() {
      if ( !promise ) {
        // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
        promise = $http.get('./json/verifyEmpty.json').then(function (response) {
          // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
          console.log(response.data);
          // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
          return response.data;
        });
      }
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});


myapp.controller('monitorCtrl', function(myService,$scope) {
    // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
    myService.get().then(function(d) {
      $scope.response = d;
    });
});

})();
```

verifyEmpty.json

```
[
 {
"name":"luis",
"lastname":"perez",
"age":27,
"gender":"m",
"haircolor":"yellow",
"eyecolor":"brown",
"student":false
 },
 {
"name":"monse",
"lastname":"chuang",
"age":28,
"gender":"f",
"haircolor":"black",
"eyecolor":"black",
"student":true
 },
 {
"name":"sarah",
"lastname":"lee",
"age":29,
"gender":"f",
"haircolor":"yellow",
"eyecolor":"green",
"student":true
 },
 {
"name":"luisa",
"lastname":"ortega",
"age":28,
"gender":"f",
"haircolor":"black",
"eyecolor":"blue",
"student":false
 },
 {
"name":"diana",
"lastname":"garcia",
"age":27,
"gender":"f",
"haircolor":"brown",
"eyecolor":"brown",
"student":true
 }
]
```

monitor.php

```
<body ng-app="appMonitor">
<div class="" ng-controller="monitorCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>name</strong></th>
      <th><strong>lastname</strong></th>
      <th><strong>age</strong></th>
      <th><strong>gender</strong></th>
      <th><strong>haircolor</strong></th>
      <th><strong>eyecolor</strong></th>
      <th><strong>student?</strong></th>
  </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="r in response" ng-cloak>
      <td>{{r.name}}</td>
      <td>{{r.lastname}}</td>
      <td>{{r.age}}</td>
      <td>{{r.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{r.haircolor}}</td>
      <td>{{r.eyecolor}}</td>
      <td ng-show="r.student">Yes</td>
  </tr>


  </table>
  <!-- {{response}} -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/148libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

No veo que el two way data binding tenga relacion con el planteo que realizas.

En realidad lo que debes implementar es un `server push` que informe al cliente cuando cambia algo en el servidor.

La verdad es que no conozco mucho de php, pero quizas librerias como ser

http://socketo.me/

podrian ayudar

La idea es que con codigo servidor detectes cuando el archivo cambia y envies una notificacion al cliente mediente `WebSocket` para que angular realice un nuevo `$http` y recupere el json actualizado

saludos

Comment: Tienes razón, lo que falta es que el servidor esté monitorizando los cambios en el archivo y envíe una notificación al cliente por websockets. En .NET tenemos SignalR y buscando para php he encontrado este interesante artículo "Building Realtime Web Apps with PHP" https://entwickler.de/webandphp/building-realtime-web-apps-with-php-125787.html. Saludos

Comment: y con angularjs no sera posible? o quizas con nodejs?

Comment: Recuerda que angular ejecuta del lado del cliente, mientras que el monitoreo del archivo y la notificacion esta del lado del servidor. Podrias hacerlo solo con angular si defines un timer y cada cierto tiempo realizas un nuevo $http para recuperar la actualizacion del json. Si lo quieres realizar en tiempo real necesites de WebSocket

Comment: @GustavoContreras claro que es posible! aqui tienes un bonito material para que revises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/ asi como dijo Leandro **La idea es que con codigo servidor detectes cuando el archivo cambia y envies una notificacion al cliente mediente WebSocket para que angular realice un nuevo $http y recupere el json actualizado** Dale con fe! exitos en el desarrollo, bendiciones